# C sscanf change other value

Tags: c, scanf

When I use sscanf, I found some other variable is changed as well but I don't know why.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int sub(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}

int mul(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}

int d(int a, int b) {
    return a / b;
}

void manipulate(int* result, int x, int y, int op(int, int)) {
    printf("%p\n", result);
    *result = op(x, y);
}

int main() {
    char line[20];
    FILE* f = fopen("sample.txt", "r");

    int result = 0;
    while (fgets(line, 15, f) != NULL) {
        char oper[3];
        char valA[3];
        char valB[3];

        sscanf(&line[0], "%s %s %s", oper, valA, valB);

        int x;
        int y;

        printf("%d\n", result);
        if (valA[0] == '%') {
            x = result;
            y = atoi(valB);
        } else if (valB[0] == '%') {
            x = atoi(valA);
            y = result;
        } else {
            x = atoi(valA);
            y = atoi(valB);
        }
        printf("%d %d\n", x, y);

        if (strcmp(oper, "ADD") == 0) {
            manipulate(&result, x, y, &add);
        } else if (strcmp(oper, "SUB") == 0) {
            manipulate(&result, x, y, &sub);
        } else if (strcmp(oper, "MUL") == 0) {
            manipulate(&result, x, y, &mul);
        } else if (strcmp(oper, "DIV") == 0)  {
            manipulate(&result, x, y, &d);
        }
    }
}
```

I used the debugger to track the value of the variable named **result**. In the first loop, the result becomes the value I want, but when it entre the second loop and finish the line sscanf, the result becomes 0 again. Could anyone tell me why? Thank you so much :)

Comment: Likely you provide more than 2-char input to one of `char oper[3];, char valA[3];` or `char valB[3];` which writes beyond the end of one of the arrays corrupting the stack. Show us your inputs. (and *never SKIMP on buffer size*) Also `atoi` provides *zero* error detection. It will happily process `atoi("my cow");` and silently return `0` as if it succeeded. Use `strtol` or `sscanf` instead.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you so much. I have address the problem. It is because the memory space is too small. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `char` arrays are too small, because you didn't account for null terminators. The string `ADD` requires 4 characters (`'A'`, `'D'`, `'D'`, and `'\0'`), but you're storing it in `char oper[3]`, and writing past the end is Undefined Behavior. In this case, that happens to mean that the `'\0'` gets stored on top of `result`, setting it to 0.

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem is solved by increasing the size of the char array, but I have one more questions. I think I declare the char variables after the variable named result. This means the address of the first char array is after the result. Therefore, why it replaces one bit from the result instead of the second char array?

Comment: @buibuibui404 Undefined behavior is just that: undefined. You can't predict what exactly will happen. The compiler just happened to line up your stuff in memory so it worked out like it did.

Comment: Make sense. Thank you so much :)